# Undeleteable 33GiB file on a 4GiB USB-Stick. fsck says "clean", Error: "Operation not permitted"

Tags: files, ext4, fsck, delete

I successfully installed a live debian 8.x on a 4G thumb-drive, like many times before. However, this time there is a 33GiB `tee.1.gz` file in `/usr/share/man/man1/`, which is much larger than a normal zipped manpage, and also "impossible", since the thumbdrive is only 4GiB big.

Attempting `rm $file`, with `-f` and without, even when mounting on a different installation, yields "Operation not permitted". `fsck.ext4 -yf` doesn't change the outcome. I also tried `unlink` and `chattr -i`.

I also tried writing to other parts of the filesystem, successfully. So the BlockDevice is mounted `rw`.

How do I get rid of this file? (It breaks `apt-get update`, because "Mandb trigger" an out-of-memory condition attempting to process `tee.1.gz`)